# php-fpm docker nginx upstream timeout error

Tags: php, nginx

I have a php-fpm setup using a nginx webserver configured with docker-compose. It works great most of them time, buts ometimes the nginx server stops responding and eventually times out with `504 Nginx Gateway Timeout`.

The nginx error log is filled with: 
`2017/08/03 08:28:57 [error] 10#0: *3512 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: XXX.XX.XX.XX, server: XXX.URL.XXX, request: "GET XXXROUTEXXX HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.18.0.2:9000", host: "XXX.URL.XXX", referrer: "XXX.URL.XXX"`

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?
The other answers on StackOverflow suggest increasing the nginx timeout period, but that doesn't really seem to be a viable solution.

Comment: That you would need to debug as to why your server is taking time. The thing is that PHP-FPM also has logging for slow response, you can enable that config and debug what goes wrong and where in FPM

Comment: Ok, so I enable php slow log in www/pool?